# What should we do about Discussions that would be on-topic for another site?

Tags: discussion, scope, discussions-space

There is a flag for Discussions that should be asked (in some form, maybe after clarifying edits) on Stack Overflow; these Discussions are usually deleted with a comment to post on the main site. However, SO is not the only programming-related site on the network. What should we do about questions that look to be on-topic on some other site?

Like with anything that's cross site, some obvious barriers are that many users (including Discussion mods) won't have the familiarity with these other sites, or the site in question might not like being recommended in this manner. But these might not always be an issue; for example, being both a Discussion mod and a regular mod, I would be in the perfect position to push something like [Does DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) Apply to Documentation?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/33529/34330) towards Writing SE were it asked on Discussions instead. But even in that case, I'm not entirely sure what type of "push" would be appropriate, a light touch (just a comment) or something heavy handed (deleting the Discussion). I'm leaning towards the former, assuming the Discussion had no other issues.

While this hasn't come up yet, it might be worthwhile to discuss beforehand.

Comment: As a Stack Overflow mod it would be nice to be able to push "Discussions" to MSO. We've seen  a couple cases of it already, but if/when the project becomes more well-known it's likely that even more users will choose to start "discussions" about the site in the Discussions feature rather than on MSO.

Comment: @HenryEcker I was planning to have Discussions vs MSO as a separate question. I think some of what's posted on MSO would be better suited to Discussions, actually.

Answer (score 5):

When it comes to Discussion space topicality, I would say that we could allow some broader definition of what is on topic, as long as it has some connections with programming.

For instance, there is software recommendation site, so technically recommendation discussions would be an on topic question for that site, but Discussions explicitly allow such posts:

[Discussions guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/discussions-guidelines)

> - Recommendations on software or tooling
>
>   - Posts must be non-promotional; if you mention a product, website, etc. that you're affiliated with, you must disclose that in
>     your post.
>   - Such posts should aim to start a discussion about the software or tool; they should not consist solely of a review/opinion.

In that light, discussions that might involve general computing or networking topics that are directly related to programming, could also be on topic for Discussions, even though questions around such topics would be off topic on the Stack Overflow Q/A part.

That would also include discussions on opinion-based things like coding styles, good coding and documentation practices, and similar, even though some could be on topic on other sites in the network.

For me the whole point of Discussions is to allow discussing the programming related topics, that are otherwise off topic on Stack Overflow, with the largest developer community on the Internet that can offer the most valuable insights, while keeping in mind general Discussions guidelines.

That means, if the post is not really a discussion starter, but a question about solving particular problem, then it would not be on topic for Discussions regardless of whether such question would be on or off topic for Stack Overflow Q/A or some other site in the network.

For instance, we might allow discussions about choosing between different servers for particular projects, but we would not allow discussion asking how to install or configure [Apache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_HTTP_Server) or some other server.